# How can I filter this list?

Tags: haskell

I have `[a]` that can be converted to `[b]`. Each `a` is distinct, but each `b` may not be. I want to filter my `[a]` on the condition that the filtered `[a]` contains no duplicates when converted to `[b]`.

Can someone help me to achieve this?

**Edit**

To serve as assistance, I'll provide an example.

```
as = [1..10]
conv = even
bs = map even as
-- bs = [False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True,False,True]
-- filter <cond> as -- [1,2]
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assume that `f` is the function that converts from `a` to `b`. You can then proceed in three steps:

1. You pair each element of your list with its image under `f`: `map (id &&& f)`;
2. You remove every pair of which the second element has already appeared in the now obtained list: `nubBy (on (==) snd)`;
3. You drop the second component of each pair: `map fst`.

Hence:

```
import Control.Arrow ((&&&))
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (nubBy)

filterOn :: Eq b => (a -> b) -> [a] -> [a]
filterOn f = map fst . nubBy ((==) `on` snd) . map (id &&& f)
```

For example:

```
> filterOn even [1 .. 10]
[1,2]
```

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to do this with a `cond :: a -> Bool` function and solely `filter`, i.e. with `(filter cond) [1..10]` yielding `[1,2]`.

The problem is that `filter` looks at each element in your array exactly once, and you have no information about previous elements.